# boost python error message:terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a main.py which I loaded in c++ and run with

```
void runscript ( std::string script )
{
    try {
        PyRun_SimpleStringFlags ( script.c_str() ,NULL );
    }
    catch ( const boost::python::error_already_set& ) {
        std::cout<<"test error"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

the main.py has line:

```
import test
```

(which is test.py)
located in the same folder inside main.py.
when test.py has an error I cannot cach what error I got, application crash with:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'

is there a way to cache which file or which line got an error?

Comment: Use a debugger to see the stack trace when the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` or `exec` instead ([doc reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/exec.html)).

```
try {
    bp::exec(script);
}
catch (bp::error_already_set) {
}
```

The real problem is getting error information from exception object.

It's easy to print exception to stdout by `PyErr_Print()` from `catch` block, but if you need more complicated analysis the code becomes cumbersome.

In `catch` block you have to get exception info by [`PyErr_Fetch`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Fetch), normalize by [`PyErr_NormalizeException`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_NormalizeException) and, say, analyze call stack by iterating over traceback objects.